# About limit value of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

For suppose a function has a limit value L at some point c, c be taken as limit point of the domain of f.
Now I want to ask that can L be limit point of codomain of f  without being in that codomain or doesn't belong and not a limit point of codomain of f.    .     Is this really possible?     I know this is a weird question.   I didn't find anything about this.

Comment: This is studied quite extensively in various areas of complex analysis, harmonic analysis, PDE theory, etc. See [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boundary+function%22+%22limit%22), for instance. Functions are defined on some set (usually an open set) and one investigates the possibilities for limits as you approach the boundary in various restricted (or entirely unrestricted) ways from within the domain. The limiting values might not be values of the function, and if you want the values to not be in the codomain, then just define the codomain to be the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break it down into the two questions.
Let $f:A\to B$, for some metric spaces $A, B$, and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$ with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$

1. Can $L$ be a limit point of $B$ without being in $B$?

If $L$ is not in $B$, there needs to be more information about where it comes from and how we can make sense of it as a limit. For example, you could mean $B\subseteq C$, for some metric space $C$, and $L\in C$. A simpler question, with the same essence, is whether the limit can lie outside the *range* of $f$

With the preliminaries aside, the answer the question is yes!

Consider $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, such that

$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   x & \text{$x\neq 1$} \\
                                    2& \text{$x=1$} \\
  \end{cases}
$

then it is clear that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}f(x) = 1$, and $1$ is a limit point of the range of $f$, but $1$ is not in the range of $f$

2. Your second question I interpret as follows: Can $L$ be outside the range of $f$, and also not be a limit point of the range of $f$?

The answer is once again yes! We need to construct a function that has an isolated point, and the function gets closer and closer to that point somehow. The simplest such function is a constant function!

Consider $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=1$.

The range of $f$ is simply $\{1\}$, which has no limit points at all as it is a finite set, and clearly $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(x)=1$ for any $c\in \mathbb R$

Comment: I am saying here for the case about codomain, not only range. For suppose,take f be a function from domain {z:|z| not equal to 0} to the {z:|z|>1} (this is codomain, range must be within it),now can it be possible that the limit of f at 0 be 0.

Comment: Here also one thing, function is given analytic on {z: |z| not equal to 0} .

Comment: @Subhajit asking about the codomain in this context is the same as asking about the range. you can basically define this function from R to R, and so it's range would become a subset of {z:|z| > 1}

Comment: I didn't understand,that how can you say codomain and range are same,,,,for ex, take f from [0,1] to [0,2] defined by f=x,

Comment: And one thing I restricted there that f should be in {z : |z|>1}

Comment: Then my question is ,,,is it possible to do have a limit value 0?

Comment: @Subhajit consider $f:\mathbb R \to [-1, 1]$ given by $f(x) = \sin (x)$. You can convert this question into a question about ranges simply by taking $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the same values, just that the codomain of the original function is now the range of the second function.

Even if you don't do this, to answer your question, your codomain set has to lie in some bigger set for the question to make sense, such as $\mathbb R$. So to simplify the question, I simply expand the codomain to be the whole set. You don't have to but the logic will be the same